# Unable to boot from usb on windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb

I have an old Pc that runs Windows XP. I would like to install windows 10 or 7 but i cant boot any of them from a usb. I usually get :boot failure reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device.
 or sometimes i get:a read disk error occurred press ctrl+alt+del to restart.
I tried to boot with the same usb on another pc and it works fine.I have also checked my Bios(ambios version 3.31a) settings and they seem alright.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you describe the steps you took to boot from the device? Have you configured everything properly and is the device bootable?

Comment: Yeah it is bootable.I used rufus to make it so.Also as i mentioned it boots fine on another pc.

Comment: Could boot from USB even be done, way back then? I can't remember doing it before Win7

Comment: Yeah i think it can be done.In the Boot Device Options it shows my usb device but when i click it , it doesnt boot.

Comment: Are you booting from the right media? What's your BIOS setup?

Comment: Yeah i am booting from the right media.

Comment: I have selected my usb to be the first device in the boot priority list

Comment: Have you tried redoing the bootable device step? The machine can't seem to find or read the bootable device.

Comment: Yes i have tried many times with windows 10 or 7

Comment: @MadMax Verified the OS images/installers are valid and working?

Comment: Yes as i said it works fine on another pc.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Windows XP. When the computer starts up, try F8 or F12 or whatever button allows to access boot options, then select USB

If you however do not have a boot options selector, you might be able to prioritize the USB when it is connected through the bios SETUP menu, then find the boot settings and move USB to the top, now every time a USB is plugged in, it will load on boot

;)

Comment: I have already done that but as i said it wont boot

Comment: @MadMax press the power button and hit random keys at the top of the keyboard like escape or something

Comment: Did you even read my post?

Answer (score 0):

Try that your hardware is supported by the OS you try to install. there is some problems occur when your hardware is not supported. happened to me when i try to install win 7 to acer laptop. It only supports OS win 8 and later

Comment: How can i find out what OS my system supports?

Comment: usually from the manufacturer. often caused this by motherboard.try and let me know the result